# Socket.io unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

So I am Trying to build a chat roulette app , when the user hits the ACCEPT button , socket connection is initiated at the client side , to make sure that only two users are connected at a time , i am using a randomId generated at the frontend and the sessionId ( sent in the cookie header of the socket instance). Out of all activeSockets a socket (other than the one currently connected) is selected for pairing. A chat object is created with id sender and reciever fields , random id associated with currently connected socket is set as the value for sender field and random id associated with socket selected out of all active sockets randomly is set as the reciever.

PROBLEM - but when i am attempting to do this both sender and reciever is set as the random id associated with the reciever socket id, My guess is that by the time the creation of Object happens , somehow the
randomId changes ? maybe because of some code not being asynchronous ?

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import http from "http";
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { actualSessionId } from "./utils/actualSessionId.js";

const DB = process.env.DATABASE_STRING.replace(
  "<password>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`database connection was successfull ! :) \n`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(
      `error - ${error} happened while attempting to connect to database :) \n `
    );
  });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    name: "sessionId",
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.DATABASE_STRING,
      collection: "sessions", // Collection name to store sessions
      ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      cookie: { secure: false },
    }),
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);

app.post("/initialize-session", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sess = req.session;
    if (!req.session.username && !req.session.randomId) {
      req.session.randomId = req.body.randomId;
      req.session.username = req.body.username;

      const mongoStore = req.sessionStore;

      const sessionId = req.sessionID;

      const sessionCollection = mongoStore.collection;

      sessionCollection.updateOne(
        { _id: sessionId },
        {
          $set: {
            randomId: req.body.randomId,
            username: req.body.username,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: "session init" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: `session init fail ${error}` });
  }
});

app.get("/check-session", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session, " -- req.session in /check-session \n");
  if (req.session.randomId && req.session.username) {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "randomId and username successfully added to the req.session \n",
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "failed " });
  }
});

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

let arrayOfSockets = [];
let activeChats = [];

io.on("connection", async (socket) => { //socket initialization

  const randomId = socket.handshake.auth.randomId; //here randomId is correct

  console.log(
    randomId, " :randomId" , socket.handshake.headers.cookie , " :cookie \n",
  ); //logging identity of socket also the unique identifier that binds socket to each session

  socket.join(randomId);

  io.of("/").sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    console.log(
      socket.handshake.auth.randomId,
      " --randomId -- unique to each browser -- \n"
    );
    arrayOfSockets.push(socket.handshake.auth.randomId);
  })


  console.log(arrayOfSockets , " ---arrayOfSockets--- \n");

  const findParnter = (array) => {
    let to =
      array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

    

    if ( to !== socket.handshake.headers.randomId) {

      console.log(to, "--to--");
      return to;
    } else {
       return findParnter(array);
    }
  }

  const to = findParnter(arrayOfSockets);// returns correct to

  let roomsCurrentUserIn = 0;
  let roomsRecieverUserIn = 0

  for ( const i of activeChats) {

    if (i.sender === randomId || i.reciever === randomId) {
      roomsCurrentUserIn = roomsCurrentUserIn + 1;
    }
    if (i.reciever === to || i.sender === to ) {
      roomsRecieverUserIn = roomsRecieverUserIn + 1;
    }
  }

  if ( roomsCurrentUserIn === 0 && roomsRecieverUserIn === 0) {
      activeChats.push({
        id: activeChats.length > 0 ? activeChats.length : 0,
        sender: randomId, //here randomId becomes to ?
        reciever: to
      });
  }

  console.log(activeChats , " --activeChats Array ---\n");



});

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

CLIENT-SIDE CODE

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const ModalDialogue = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");

  
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handlePartnerCoupling = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const randomId = window.localStorage.getItem("randomId");
    const username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");

    const userDetails = { randomId, username };

    axios
      .get("https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/randomuser", {
        headers: {
          "X-Api-Key": "CPX1n5e+7IijyO6G30sQvg==IVX3zJCpIcL2Paro",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data, " --random userdetails ");
      })
      .finally(() => {

        const socket = io("http://localhost:6040", {
          withCredentials: true,
          auth: {
            randomId
          }
        });

        socket.on("welcome-message", (msg) => {
          console.log(msg, " message from room");
        });

        /*
    FIND A PARNTER COMPLETE PAIRING CREATE A ROOM AND A ROOM ID USING TWO 
    UNIQUE SOCKET IDENTFIERS , USE THAT ROOM ID AT THE END OF THE ROUTE ,
    EACH COMPONENT THAT IS RENDERED AT THESE CUSTOM ROUTES ARE GOING TO BE 
    DIFFERENT 
    */

        setShowModal(false);
        //navigate("/chats/new");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div
      id="Modal-Dialogue-Background"
      className="w-screen h-screen flex flex-col bg-opacity-40 bg-slate-300 justify-center items-center absolute "
    >
      <button
        id="Modal-Close-btn-absolute"
        className="bg-inherit text-white font-bold text-lg absolute top-0 right-0 border-transparent"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setShowModal(false);
        }}
      >
        X
      </button>

      <div
        id="Modal-Dialogue-Main"
        className="flex flex-col p-2 sm:p-4 justify-center rounded-md shadow-md items-center w-1/4 text-txt1 text-xl bg-bg2"
      >
        <div
          id="Modal-Content"
          className="flex  text-lg tracking-wide font-bold justify-center items-center text-black"
        >
          Hello, {document.cookie /*this returns nothing */} Let's keep our
          conversations positive and inclusive. Please refrain from using
          abusive language or engaging in racist behavior. Together, we create a
          space where everyone feels valued. Thank you for your cooperation!
        </div>
        <button
          id="Modal-OK"
          className="text-lg text-txt2 border-transparent"
          style={{ display: `` }}
          onClick={(e) => handlePartnerCoupling(e)}
        >
          ACCEPT
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically when trying to create a ActiveChat object with the id of the participants stored in an array corresponding to the participants field , to be stored in the ActiveChats array make sure that the randomId associated with the current User is not the same as the recievers , also when creating arrayOfSockets see to it that duplicates are not stored.

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import http from "http";
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { actualSessionId } from "./utils/actualSessionId.js";

const DB = process.env.DATABASE_STRING.replace(
  "<password>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`database connection was successfull ! :) \n`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(
      `error - ${error} happened while attempting to connect to database :) \n `
    );
  });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    name: "sessionId",
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.DATABASE_STRING,
      collection: "sessions", // Collection name to store sessions
      ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      cookie: { secure: false },
    }),
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);

app.post("/initialize-session", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sess = req.session;
    if (!req.session.username && !req.session.randomId) {
      req.session.randomId = req.body.randomId;
      req.session.username = req.body.username;

      const mongoStore = req.sessionStore;

      const sessionId = req.sessionID;

      const sessionCollection = mongoStore.collection;

      sessionCollection.updateOne(
        { _id: sessionId },
        {
          $set: {
            randomId: req.body.randomId,
            username: req.body.username,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: "session init" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: `session init fail ${error}` });
  }
});

app.get("/check-session", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session, " -- req.session in /check-session \n");
  if (req.session.randomId && req.session.username) {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "randomId and username successfully added to the req.session \n",
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "failed " });
  }
});

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

let arrayOfSockets = [];
let activeChats = [];

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  //socket initialization

  const randomId = socket.handshake.auth.randomId; //here randomId is correct

  console.log(
    randomId,
    " :randomId",
    socket.handshake.headers.cookie,
    " :cookie \n"
  ); //logging identity of socket also the unique identifier that binds socket to each session

  socket.join(randomId);

  io.of("/").sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    console.log(
      socket.handshake.auth.randomId,
      " --randomId (from)  -- unique to each browser -- \n"
    );
    if (!arrayOfSockets.includes(socket.handshake.auth.randomId)) {
      arrayOfSockets.push(socket.handshake.auth.randomId);
    } //REMOVES DUPLICATES
  });

  console.log(arrayOfSockets, " ---arrayOfSockets--- \n");

  const findParnter = (array) => {
    let to = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

    if (to !== socket.handshake.headers.randomId) {
      console.log(to, "--to--");
      return to;
    } else {
      return findParnter(array);
    }
  };

  const to = findParnter(arrayOfSockets); // returns correct to

  console.log(to, " ---to--- \n");

  let roomsCurrentUserIn = 0;
  let roomsreceiverUserIn = 0;

  for (const i of activeChats) {
    if (i.sender === randomId || i.receiver === randomId) {
      roomsCurrentUserIn = roomsCurrentUserIn + 1;
    }
    if (i.receiver === to || i.sender === to) {
      roomsreceiverUserIn = roomsreceiverUserIn + 1;
    }
  }

  if (roomsCurrentUserIn === 0 && roomsreceiverUserIn === 0) {
    if (arrayOfSockets.length > 1 && randomId !== to) { //CREATES CHATS ONLY IF AT LEAST 2 SOCKETS IS CONNECTED AND IF BOTH THEIR RANDOM IDS ARE DIFFERENT

      activeChats.push({
        id: activeChats.length > 0 ? activeChats.length : 0,
        sender: randomId, //here randomId becomes to ?
        receiver: to,
      });

    }
    
  }

  console.log(activeChats, " --activeChats Array --- \n");

  for (const i of activeChats) {
    if (i.sender !== i.receiver) {
    }
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.